# Writing a vector as the sum of it's range and null space components

Tags: matrices

In my course notes I have:

> For Ax = b, given A, any m-vector b can be written uniquely as the sum of its range and null space components, so: $b = b_R + b_N , b_R \in \mathrm{range}(A), b_N \in \mathrm{null}(A^T)$

Why is this the case? I understand that the $\mathrm{null}(\mathbf{A}) = \{ \mathbf{x} : \mathbf{Ax} = 0 \}$ but not how this would could form part of any vector b in the range(A).

Also what happens if the nullspace is just {0}?

Comment: look up the normal equations

Answer (score 1):

Note that $b_N \in \operatorname{null}(A^T)$, the nullspace of the *transpose* of $A$, also called the *cokernel* of $A$, **not** the nullspace of $A$.

This follows from a part of the the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra), which states that
$$\operatorname{null}(A^T) = \operatorname{range}(A)^\perp,$$
i.e. that the orthogonal complement to the range is the cokernel, i.e. together they span the entire codomain of $A$.

Let's say $A$ is $m \times n$, since you said that $b$ is an $m$-vector. If $\operatorname{null}(A^T) = \{0\}$, then the rank of $A$ must be $m$ by the fundamental theorem, so the range of $A$ is the entire space, and you would not need $b_N$, i.e. any vector $b$ can be written $b = b_R$ where $b_R \in \operatorname{range}(A)$.